# What exactly does typedef struct node {...} Node; represent?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, declaration

Please view this block of code:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} 
Node;
```

In this code, is `Node` synonymous to `struct node`, as defined by typedef, or is `node` synonymous to struct? If the latter is the case, then is `struct node *next;` equivalent to `struct struct *next;`?

Am I overcomplicating things?

Comment: Your struct is part of a construct usually called "linked list". Search for it if you want to know how to use it and why you wrote `struct node *next`. As for your question, with `struct node { ... };` in your code you would have to declare variables as `struct node mynode1;`. Using `typedef struct node Node;` you just have to write `Node mynode1`

Comment: I think it generates an error... `Node* hashtable[SIZE]`, on the other side, generates an array with SIZE elements; each of them is a pointer to a struct node (and so, since every struct can be considered the head of a list, it's an array of SIZE lists, or it can be an array with pointers to various elements of the same list, it depends on how you use it)

Comment: @frarugi87 Why does `int x;` declare a pointer to an int named x without a pointee, while `Node* hashtable[SIZE];` declares an array of SIZE pointers pointing to `Node` (`Node` being the pointee)?

Comment: No, `int x;` does not declare a pointer to an int. It declares and defines an int. `int* x;` declares a pointer to an int, the same as `Node* onenode`. Then, just like `int arr[2]` declares an array of two ints, and  `int* arr[2]` declares an array of two pointers to int, `Node* arr[2]` declares an array of two pointers to `struct node`, AKA `Node`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use `typedef` you create an *alias* of some type.

So yes, `Node` is an alias for `struct node`.

---

Also, the code you have is equivalent to

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node Node;
```

The `typedef` is not part of the structure definition, it part of the `Node` definition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Also, does node* hashtable[SIZE]; declare a struct pointer to an array named hashtable of some size?

Comment: @PurpleYoshiii If you mean `Node* hashtable[SIZE];` (note the uppecase `N` in `Node`), then that's a declaration of an array of `SIZE` pointers to `Node`. Basically an array of lists in this specific case.

Comment: So, `Node* hashtable[SIZE];` declares an array of SIZE pointers pointing to `Node`? If that is the case, then why does `int* x;` only declare an int pointer named x without a pointee, while `Node* hashtable[SIZE];` declares an array of SIZE pointers pointing to `Node` (`Node` being the pointee).

Comment: Why does `int* x;` only declare an int pointer named x without a pointee, while `Node* hashtable[SIZE];` declares an array of SIZE pointers pointing to Node (`Node` being the pointee)?

Comment: @PurpleYoshiii I'm not sure I understand what you mean? In your example `x` is simply an uninitialized pointer to `int` (you could point to a single integer, or an array (compile-time or dynamically allocated). The variable `hashtable` is an array of equally uninitialized pointers to `Node`. It's like asking what's the different between `Node *a_pointer` and `Node *array_of_pointers[SIZE]`, those are simply two different declarations that declares two different variables of two different types.

Comment: To clarify, `Node *hashtable[SIZE];` isn't actually pointing to anything inside the structure but only declaring a pointer to the structure?

Comment: @PurpleYoshiii Yes. You *do* know how arrays work, right? Like e.g. `int array_of_int[SOME_SIZE];`? An array of pointers is just like any other array, and in your case each element in the `hashtable` array is a `Node *` (or `struct node *`).

Answer (score 5):

`Node` is synonymous to `struct node`. Thats why (for your example) instead of using

```
struct node* p;
```

One can use

```
Node* p;
```

Answer (score 4):

In the C grammar structures are defined the following way

struct-or-union-specifier:
    struct-or-union identifier<sub>opt</sub> { struct-declaration-list }

So to refer this structure specifier you need to use its name.

You may declare variables the following way

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;
```

Here `Node` is an object of type `struct node`. In turn `struct node` is a type specifier of variable `Node`.

You may omit the identifier in a structure specifier. In this case the structure is called *unnamed* structure. However using such a structure you can not refer to it itself inside its definition. For example you may not write

```
struct 
{
    int data;
    struct *next;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
} Node;
```

because it is unknown what structure is referred to here.

You may use unnamed structures as members of other structures. In this case such a structure is named *anonymous* structure and its members become members of the enclosing structure.

For example

```
struct A
{
   struct
   {
       int x;
       int y;
   ];
   int z;
};
```

This structure `A` has three members `x`, `y`, and `z`.

When the storage-class specifier is used then the declarator is an identifier to be a typedef name that denotes the type specified for the identifier.

Thus in this declaration

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;
```

`Node` is not already an object. It is a type name that denotes struct node.

So from now you may use type name `Node` instead of the type specifier `struct node`

Answer (score 2):

you no longer have to write `struct` all over the place. That not only saves keystrokes, it also can make the code cleaner since it provides a smidgen more abstraction.

Stuff like

```
typedef struct {
  int x, y;
} Point;

Point point_new(int x, int y)
{
  Point a;
  a.x = x;
  a.y = y;
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} 
Node;
```

This can be understood simply by

```
struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

    typedef  struct node Node;
```

---

```
struct [structure tag or label] {

   member definition;
   ...
   member definition;
} [one or more structure variables];
```

new variable can be defined as :

```
struct label <variable>;
```

or if you use typedef struct label need not to be repeated every time to define new structure variable
i.e

```
typedef struct label Node;
```

Now Node can be use to define new similar type of variable.

Comment: in fact, it is `typedef struct node Node;`, not just `node`

Comment: Thanks I forgot that one :-)